# Get keys from multidimensional array according to other keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I have a multidimensional array like this which I converted from JSON:

```
Array (

    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Test
        [id]   => [1]
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [name] => Hello
        [id]   => [2]
    )
)
```

How can I return the value of `id` if `name` is equal to the one the user provided? (e.g if the user typed "Test", I want it to return "1")

Edit: Here's the code that works if anyone wants it:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("json.json"), true);
foreach($array as $item) {
    if($item["name"] == "Test")
        echo $item["id"];
}
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it manually like, in some function:

```
   function find($items, $something){
       foreach($items as $item)
       {
          if ($item["name"] === $something)
             return $item["id"];
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The classical solution is to simply iterate over the array with `foreach` and check the `name` of each row. When it matches your search term you have found the `id` you are looking for, so `break` to stop searching and do something with that value.

If you are using PHP 5.5, a convenient solution that works well with less-than-huge data sets would be to use [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$indexed = array_column($data, 'id', 'name');
echo $indexed['Test']; // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
function searchObject($value,$index,$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val[$index] === $value)
            return $val;
    }
    return null;
}

$MyObject= searchObject("Hello","name",$MyArray);
$id = $MyObject["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
$count = count($array);
$name = $_POST['name']; //the name which user provided
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
  if($array[$i]['name']==$name)
  {
   echo $i;
   break;
  }
}
```

enjoy

Comment: Using `for` instead of `foreach` is almost always a bad idea. In this case it makes the code unnecessarily brittle: if the input changes slightly it will stop working (or worse, working correctly all of the time).

Comment: yeah you are right .. but I like to give the answers which are easy to understant for the asker ... @Jon

Comment: @NishantSolanki Well, I've never understood for loops :P The output: `Unexpected $end on line 14`

Comment: @Will ..there is a problem in your array structure...
`[id]=>[2]` ... the value should not be in `square brackets`.. it should be in `commas` ..

Comment: @NishantSolanki: I don't see how `for` is easier to understand than `foreach`. The manual itself says *"The `foreach` construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays."*

Comment: @Jon ok ok brada. Will use `foreach` from the next tym. :)

Comment: @Will you must be missing a `semicolon ;` somewhere.. thats why you got that `error`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$name = "Test";

foreach($your_array as $arr){
  if($arr['name'] == $name){
     echo $arr['id'];
  }
}
```